# Prevent AngularJs reload on direct inner page view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

For example
In my angular website I have 2 pages called /app , /app/users

If someone visits /app page it displays app.html content

i) When user navigate from /app page to /app/users page angular is fetching users.html and displays inside /app.html 's ui-view.

ii) But if user visits /app/users page directly then my server routing this into users-full-page.html page which have both app.html and users.html codes. Also it have same AngularJs functionality. (Am doing this for SEO purpose)

Now the problem is, In my second case when user visit directly into /app/users page after the page load Angular reloading the users.html content again which already loaded directly from server

So how to prevent this?

Note

Actually I don't have error or problem on Angular code anywhere to show. It's working. I want to prevent one of its feature. When user navigate /app/users page it loading users.html content without problem. But when user visits /app/users page directly I already loaded users.html content in server side itself. So I don't want angular to load it again. So I need to prevent

Comment: you need to enable rewrites on your server, since you are now using virtual directories in your angular app.  Which server stack are you using?  there are examples of common server configurations here:  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: server rewrite already working fine. After the page load AngularJs only reloading users.html content again which already loaded directly. I want to prevent this

Comment: you'll need to show some code to demonstrate what you are talking about; there isn't any normal reason for angular to load the same data twice....

Comment: the edit still doesn't explain what you are trying to do.  It *sounds* like you want to load a page called users.html, then have it redirect to a different page with your angular app on it, but retain the data passed from the first page, which doesn't really make sense.